# Is there any manifold learning literature where the both the ambient dimension and intrinsic dimension of the data are high?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, large-data, high-dimensional, manifold-learning

I'm new to manifold learning, and from my understanding it normally denotes a subject which starts with the assumption that the data $\{x_1 \dots x_n\} \subset (M,g) \subset \mathbb{R}^p,$ where $(M,g)$ is a differential manifold with a Riemmanian metric $g,$ of dimension $m,$ where **$m <<p, p$ is high, $m$ is low.** *I've never seen any literature where we assume that the intrinsic dimension of the data $m$ is also high, say when $p$ increases, it does in a way so that $p=O(m)$.*

I'd appreciate if you could point me to such literature, if they exist. Also, *what do you think is **significantly and fundamentally different** while we assume that $p,m$ are both large and comparable, as opposed to only $p$ is large, but $m$ isn't?*

Thanks a ton!